# Adding an image as textview's text background

Tags: java, android, xml

Recently I've wanted to do something artsy with my new project like, as the title suggests, add a background image as a text's background, rather than the typical constant color all around. Specifically, I have a gradient image for this text.

Something like this

[image]

Typically I would expect an xml drawable resource file type solution, but any simple solution is greatly appreciated

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all the shader solutions, but for the sake of the question, only answers that provide a solution regarding image backgrounds will be accepted/given bounty

Comment: I haven't tried it, but [Chiu-ki Chan has this gradient text example](https://github.com/chiuki/advanced-textview/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sqisland/android/advanced_textview/GradientTextActivity.java).

Comment: works quite well for a linear gradient, thanks. Will definitely consider using this.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "image backgrounds"? How is that different than a bitmap?

Comment: File.jpeg >> background of image

Answer (score 6):

You can apply a `BitmapShader` to the `TextView` paint.

```
myTextView.getPaint().setShader(new BitmapShader(myBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
```

There are other types of shaders if you don't want to use an image.  Documentation is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Shader.html).

Answer (score 5):

**[Shader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Shader.html)** is the based class for objects that return horizontal spans of colors during drawing. A subclass of ***Shader is installed in a Paint calling paint.setShader(shader)***. After that any object (other than a bitmap) that is drawn with that paint will get its color(s) from the shader.

```
        Bitmap bitmapObj  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.your_image);
        Shader shaderObj = new BitmapShader(bitmapObj,Shader.TileMode.REPEAT,Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        textViewObj.getPaint().setShader(shaderObj);
        textViewObj.setText("hello");
```

You should call proper **[Shader.TileMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Shader.TileMode.html)**

You can also follow

1. **[Gradient TextView](http://snowpard-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/interface-gradient-textview.html)**
2. **[Textview Gradient Text](https://android--examples.blogspot.in/2015/11/android-how-to-apply-textview-text.html)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `yourTextView.getPaint().setShader(new LinearGradient(...));`

There are two constructor for `LinearGradient` :

```
/** Create a shader that draws a linear gradient along a line.
    @param x0           The x-coordinate for the start of the gradient line
    @param y0           The y-coordinate for the start of the gradient line
    @param x1           The x-coordinate for the end of the gradient line
    @param y1           The y-coordinate for the end of the gradient line
    @param  colors      The colors to be distributed along the gradient line
    @param  positions   May be null. The relative positions [0..1] of
                                each corresponding color in the colors array. If this is null,
                                the the colors are distributed evenly along the gradient line.
    @param  tile        The Shader tiling mode
*/

public LinearGradient(float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1, int colors[], float positions[], TileMode tile)
```

And

```
/** Create a shader that draws a linear gradient along a line.
    @param x0       The x-coordinate for the start of the gradient line
    @param y0       The y-coordinate for the start of the gradient line
    @param x1       The x-coordinate for the end of the gradient line
    @param y1       The y-coordinate for the end of the gradient line
    @param  color0  The color at the start of the gradient line.
    @param  color1  The color at the end of the gradient line.
    @param  tile    The Shader tiling mode
*/
public LinearGradient(float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1, int color0, int color1, TileMode tile)
```

Documentation of Shaders:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Shader.html

Documentation of Shaders.TileMode :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Shader.TileMode.html

---

Another way (as the idea and not tested):

Convert text to bitmap and drawable, then use [GradientDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html)

Answer (score 1):

create gradient.xml in drawable folder. You can set the angle and start and end color. Set this drawable as the background

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
     <gradient
    android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:angle="45"/>    
    </shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving load on the gpu / system by using shaders and stuff suggested by above answers, would recommend you using relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/your_imageview_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="As_you_want_dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/your_textview_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```